# iOS: how to force updates of superview while subview animates?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I've got three views:

- view1 -- just a small blue square.
- view2 -- just a small red square.
- Superview -- contains the other two.  Superview's `drawRect:` routine draws a line that connects the center of view1 to view2.

All of this (above) works.

What I want to do is animate the position of (say) view1, with something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: duration
                 animations: ^{
                     view1.center = newPoint;
                 }
 ];
```

Ok, that works -- view1 moves as expected.  But what I ***WANT*** that's not happening is: I want `Superview` to be updated (`setNeedsDisplay` ...?) constantly while the animation is happening, such that the drawn line remains connected.

How do I do that?

(NOTE: I know how to use the layer to get the position of a view in motion -- that's not the question.  The question is how to trigger the update of `Superview` throughout the animation.  I could set a timer or something silly, but I was hoping for a built-in solution.)

Thanks!

Comment: What about specifying the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent` option to the animation?

Comment: @maddy: I think that would allow animations to take place in the animated view.  (Example, if `view1` as a `UIImageView` with animating images.)  I don't think that'll help my `Superview` keep up to date, since it's not involved in the UIView-Animation.  (Whew! :) )